# How I can delete image from DB in Yii?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

how i can delete the image 
this is my view

```
<?php if(!empty($model->image_name) > 0) { ?>
        <div class="row">
                    <?php echo CHtml::image(Img::getPostThumb($model->image_name, 700, 1000));?>
                    <b><?php echo CHtml::link('delete', array('MobileLandingPost/DeleteImage','imageName'=>$model->image_name,'id'=>$model->id),array('confirm' => 'سنقوم بحذف الصور موافق ؟'));?></b>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function actionDeleteImage($imageName,$id){ 

        $model= MobileLandingPost::model()->find(array(
                                         'condition'=>'image_name=:image_name ',
                                         'params'=>array(':temp_posts_id'=>$imageName))

                                   );       

        if(!$model)
        {    
                    throw new CHttpException(404,'الصورة التي تريد حذفها غير موجودة');
        }

        if($model->delete())
        {   

                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','تم حذف الصورة');
                    $this->redirect( array('MobileLandingPost/Update','id'=>$id));

        } 


}
```

when i press delete all the model delete
but i need to delete just the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Delete that field only & save model.

```
$model->image_name = '';
$model->save();
```

Comment: try `if (!$model->save()) { print_r($model->getErrors()); }`

Comment: thank you mr Harikrishnan but i think the problem is if($model->delete())
        {   

                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','تم حذف الصورة');
                    $this->redirect( array('MobileLandingPost/Update','id'=>$id));

        }